# How to create a weighted heatmap using R Leaflet?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I am attempting to create a heatmap using a data set that has only one value per coordinate, with that value being a continuous variable.  All of the examples I have found using `leaflet.extras::addHeatmap()` use data that can have multiple values per coordinate, and create the heatmap based on the density of counts in an area. There doesn't seem to be a way to pass a weight instead.

My ultimate goal is to have something that looks like a raster based on these values:

[image]

However I don't want to use a raster due to the pixelation along the coasts.

When I pass the data to `addHeatmap()` and include the argument `intensity = ~my_weighted_value`, I get something like this:

[image]

And at increased zoom levels, it just ends up being a bunch of circles:

[image]

What is the proper way to take weighted spatial data and add a heatmap that looks like the raster?

Comment: Can you share your dataset by pasting the output of dput(your_df)

Answer (score 0):

Try to scale my_weighted_value back by *.00001 or something. Your weighted value appears to be exceeding the max.